# Routes get error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two `get` methods in `routes.rb`

```
get 'orders/:id-:phone', to: 'orders#show', as: :order_phone
get ':id/:url', to: 'point_pages#show', as: :page_url
```

So, for `Order` model I need to have URL like: `domain.com/orders/1-88888888888` (88888888888 - is a phone number of `order.user`) and for `PointPage` model - `domain.com/1/some_long_point_page_url`.

But when I create new `Order` and rails `redirect to order_phone_path(@order)`, I receive an error:

```
Couldn't find PointPage with id=orders
```

So, I need to tell rails, that when URL is `domain.com/orders/...`, it uses the first `get` method for `Order`, and when URL is `domain.com/1-...` (or other number) it uses the second `get` method for `PointPage`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to use a route as such then swap the position of `get` method calls as:

```
get ':id/:url', to: 'point_pages#show', as: :page_url
get 'orders/:id-:phone', to: 'orders#show', as: :order_phone
```

This way the first route catches your URI.  Note that the order of routes defined is important.  If two routes match a given pattern then the route defined earlier is used.

**Note** that with this definition:

```
get ':id/:url', to: 'point_pages#show', as: :page_url
```

all your routes would get caught by it.  So, it's definitely advised to prepend path to the controller or some unique literal before any variables. E.g:

```
 get 'point_pages/:id/:url', to: 'point_pages#show', as: :page_url
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. For SEO purposes I don't need any other strings in URI for PointPage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll may want to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :point_pages, only: [], path: "" do
   get :url, action: :show, as: :page_url # -> domain.com/:id/:url to show
end

resources :orders, only: [] do
   get ":id-:phone", action: :show, on: :collection, as: :order_phone # -> domain.com/orders/:id-:phone
end
```

This might look a little haphazard, but it's definitely the best way to keep your application's routes as convention would direct.

I know you have the answer, so hopefully this will give you some better understanding of how you may benefit from structuring the routes as above